# Printing Mathematical Symbols in Java Gives Wrong Output

Tags: java, unicode, printing

I am trying to print using the TextLayout class.  When I print some mathematical symbols, I get odd behavior.

The image below shows the results from printing the strings "First + 2" and "First \u222A 2" to a PDF file.  When the 'union' symbol (\u222A) is printed, it looks like characters following the symbol overwrite characters before the symbol.

[image]

Here is the test code that prints a string that does not contain \u222A and another string that does:

```
public class PrintTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    pj.setPrintable(new Printable() {
        public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int pageIndex) {
            if (pageIndex != 0) return NO_SUCH_PAGE;

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Font font = new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 10);

            // Draw string with + char
            TextLayout layout = new TextLayout("First + 2", font, g2
                    .getFontRenderContext());
            layout.draw(g2, 40, 80);

            // Draw string with union character
            layout = new TextLayout("First \u222A 2", font, g2
                    .getFontRenderContext());
            layout.draw(g2, 40, 100);

            return PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    });

    if (pj.printDialog()) {
        try {
            pj.print();
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

I am running java 1.7.0_17 on Windows 7 & 8, and have tested this on several printers, including printing to PDF.  All tests show the same problem.  I get the same results with 'union', 'intersection' and 'exclusion' symbols.

I am really stuck here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: The problem seems to occur when using logical fonts.  I tested with all of the installed logical fonts ('Dialog', 'DialogInput', 'Monospaced, 'SansSerif' and 'Serif') and got the same problem.  When I tested with physical fonts that support these symbols ('Lucida Sans' and 'Arial Unicode MS') I got the desired output.

[image]

This resolves the immediate issue for me since I'm not tied to using logical fonts.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you are printing Unicode characters all the time; the title of your post suggests you are printing something other than Unicode.  All the alphabetic characters that you print correctly are encoded in Unicode, since that is how Java encodes strings.

So you are trying to print the "Union" symbol, and it isn't working.  What evidence do you have that it is supported on the printer you are printing on?  It is quite possibly not supported on any printer you've tried, hence unpredictable behavior.  It is the most obvious thing that could cause this.

Comment: The union character is printed, but the characters that follow it are printed over the characters that precede it.

Comment: ok, I agree that is strange, and indicates a problem I am not familiar with.  But in seeking help for it, don't refer to the other characters as "non-Unicode", because that is incorrect.  What you have is a less-often-used Unicode character that causes what looks like an immediate carriage return (without a line feed).  I don't know what would do that.  If you have any other method by which to output this character to this printer, those results would be interesting.  You might try printing to a file with a special driver like cutePdf and see what that does.  Good luck with it.

Comment: Thanks for the input rcook.  I have modified the title and text to reflect your comments.  I also attached an image of the the output I get when writing to Nitro PDF Creator.

Comment: Not an answer; should have been posted as a comment.